# Google Sheets Bottom Up Vlookup Over Multiple Tabs

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, reverse

Hey I have an issue with trying to do a reverse order lookup or a bottom up vlookup

My formula is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A,{'movement co'!C:R;bfitt!C:R;gladstone!C:R;parkhurst!C:R;mayfield!C:R;alexandria!C:R;'crows nest'!C:R;newtown!C:R;'gregory hills'!C:R;annandale!C:R;graceville!C:R;'south penrith'!C:R;'north melbourne'!C:R;'back on track'!C:R;'elsternwick'!C:R;'brighton'!C:R},{16,2,3,4,15,10,5},0)))
```

This looks over multiple tabs/sheets to gather the data which works fine, but I need it to look at the last added row which I can't seem to make work with a sort function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data to give me a better idea of what do you want to achieve? It would be great if you can give some example of the sorted data.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3:A, SORT(
 {'movement co'!C:R,     ROW('movement co'!C:R);
  bfitt!C:R,             ROW(bfitt!C:R); 
  gladstone!C:R,         ROW(gladstone!C:R);
  parkhurst!C:R,         ROW(parkhurst!C:R);
  mayfield!C:R,          ROW(mayfield!C:R);
  alexandria!C:R,        ROW(alexandria!C:R); 
  'crows nest'!C:R,      ROW('crows nest'!C:R);
  newtown!C:R,           ROW(newtown!C:R);
  'gregory hills'!C:R,   ROW('gregory hills'!C:R);
  annandale!C:R,         ROW(annandale!C:R);
  graceville!C:R,        ROW(graceville!C:R);
  'south penrith'!C:R,   ROW('south penrith'!C:R);
  'north melbourne'!C:R, ROW('north melbourne'!C:R);
  'back on track'!C:R,   ROW('back on track'!C:R);
  'elsternwick'!C:R,     ROW('elsternwick'!C:R);
  'brighton'!C:R,        ROW('brighton'!C:R)}, 17, 0), 
 {16, 2, 3, 4, 15, 10, 5}, 0)))
```

Comment: Sorry, everything was just blank

Comment: @DaleNelson can you share a copy of your sheet?